# Websphere Web Service Has Different Namespaces On Different Deployments

Tags: web-services, websphere

I have a java webapp that exposes several webservice endpoints that appear to be behaving slightly differently under different deployments.

Were using IBM Websphere 6.1 in all environments.

The namespace on the requests that the service expects differs whether I deploy the ear locally or on the test env - i.e.

**Test Env Request:**

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:look="http://com.XXXX.bi/lookup">
   <soapenv:Header>
      <look:Password>XXXXX</look:Password>
      <look:Username>XXXXX</look:Username>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <look:Lookup>
         <Role>Admin</Role>
         <ID>AB1234</ID>
         <Name>Bob Smith</Name>
         <DOB>1901-01-01</DOB>         
      </look:Lookup>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

**Local Request:**

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:look="http://com.XXXX.bi/lookup">
   <soapenv:Header>
      <look:Password>XXXXX</look:Password>
      <look:Username>XXXXX</look:Username>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <look:Lookup>
         <look:Role>Admin</look:Role>
         <look:ID>AB1234</look:ID>
         <look:Name>Bob Smith</look:Name>
         <look:DOB>1901-01-01</look:DOB>         
      </look:Lookup>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Both the services on each environment function correctly and in the same manner.
The WSDLs are both identical.

I'm pretty sure this is going to end up being a Websphere config issue as I'm deploying the same ear in both circumstances, but I cant spot any differences between the envs.

Anyone got any ideas what I would need to change?

Thanks